# How to align bar plot labels to the left and right of a horizontal bar plot in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a horizontal bar plot and would like to align my bar labels to the left and right of each bar like shown below:
[image]

ie. I want the labels left aligned if the bar plot has a positive value and right aligned if the bar plot has a negative value.

Use the code below as a workable example:

```
value <- c(3,2,1,-1,-2,-3)
label <- factor(c("Arnold","Bob","Chris","David","Emma","Frank"))

df <- data.frame(value, label)

ggplot(df, aes(x = reorder(label, value), y = value)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    geom_text(aes(y = 0, label = label)) +
    coord_flip() +
    labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
    theme_classic() +
    theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank())
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an `hjust` aesthetic to `geom_text`, like this...

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = reorder(label, value), y = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(y = 0, label = label, hjust = 0.5 + 0.5 * sign(value))) +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not as elegant as @AndrewGustar's answer but an `ifelse` would also do:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = reorder(label, value), y = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(y = 0, label = label, hjust = ifelse(value > 0, 1.1, -.1))) +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    axis.line.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank()
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach, using `subset()` to create two separate data frames for positive and negative values and using two `geom_text` each for positive and negative: We finally have to adapt the `nudge_x` and `hjust`.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = reorder(label, value), y = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(data = subset(df, value >= 0),
            aes(x = value, y = 0, label = label),
            hjust = 1.3, nudge_x = 3) +
  geom_text(data = subset(df, value < 0),
            aes(x = value, y = 0, label = label),
            hjust = -0.3, nudge_x = 4) +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank())
```

[image]